# Ruby On Rails - creating an object does not respect validations and showing error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, missing-template

I'm having troubles handling objects that not respect the validation.
I'm building an app in which an user can create a "**Trip**" model and then add steps to his trip, that I called "**Traces**". Each added *trace* prints a new part of a map present in the *trip#show* action.
The association between models is *user has_many trips* and *trip has_many traces*

In the *users#show* I put a "CREATE NEW TRIP" button linking to the *trips#new* and here I have the form_for with the field corresponding to the **Trip** attributes.
When I fill the form correctly everything is ok. When something is missing or wrong (for the validations) I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Trips#create
undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class
```

------ in the **trips_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @trip = current_user.trips.build(params[:trip])
  if @trip.save
    # handle a successful save
    flash[:success] = 'Trip created!'
    redirect_to user_trip_path(@trip, user_id: current_user.id)
    else
    @trip = []
    @feed_items = []
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

------ in *app/views/trip*, in the **new.html.erb**

```
h1>Create a trip</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 general-input">
    <%= form_for ([current_user, @trip]) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.label :name,'Give a name to your trip ;)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :trip_start, 'Choose your starting point!' %>
    <%= f.text_field :trip_start %>
    <%= f.label :departure, 'When are you leaving?' %>
    <%= f.date_select :departure, :start_year => Date.current.year   %>
    <%= f.label :arrive, 'And coming back home?' %>
    <%= f.date_select :arrive, :start_year => Date.current.year %>

    <%= f.submit 'Create a new trip', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 1: problem solving removing @trace=[ ] from trips_controller.rb**

---

**EDIT 2:**

I also have a similar problem with the creation of a new Trace:

The form for adding a new *trace* is in the *trip#show* page.
When I try to create a trace that not respects the validation (e.g. if I leave blank the "destination" field) I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#create
undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

When I'm on the Trip page where the form for the Traces is placed, the URL is like:

```
 http://localhost:3000/users/2/trips/8
```

but when I create a not valide Trace it switchs to a path like:

```
 http://localhost:3000/trips/8/posts
```

I suppose I'm doing something wrong handling the error messages. I probably misunderstood something, even because I'm new to Rails and web programming in general.

Here you are some code parts, hoping it helps to understand my mistake:

------ in the **traces_controller.rb**

```
def create
 @trip= Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
 @trace = @trip.traces.create(params[:trace])
  if @trace.save
   flash[:success] = 'Trace created!'
   redirect_to user_trip_path(@trip, user_id: current_user.id)
   else
   @trace=[]
   render 'trips/show'
 end
end
```

------ in *app/views/shared*, in the **add_trace_form.html.erb**

```
<p>Complete your trip adding a route!</p>
 <%= form_for ([@trip, @trip.traces.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="block post-form">
  <div class="field ">
  <%= f.text_field :end, placeholder: 'Where are you going next?' %>
  <%= f.label :arr_day, 'When?' %>
  <%= f.date_select :arr_day, :start_year => Date.current.year   %>

  <%= f.submit 'Add route', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-landing' %>
   </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

------ in *app/views/shared*, in the **error_messages.html.erb**

```
 <% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
    The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
     <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li>* <%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

------ in the **routes.rb**

```
resources :users do  
  resources :trips
end

resources :trips do
  resources :traces
end

resources :traces
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try removing `@trip = []` in the create action to get rid of first error.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot :) So, just to know, when do I need to put an empty vector in the else case?

Answer (score 0):

i think when you are passing the f.object in locales in render its is passing array not the active record object ,<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>.
Can u check inspecting object in your partial and what class it has.
Try inspecting object.errors.inspect
 Try refering http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials